# Problem of using unsigned long long int and long long int in program to calculate power of number

Tags: c

I have written two functions to find power of positive and negative number in c but it is not printing anything

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Driver(int NUMBER, int EXPO, int ans){
    while(EXPO>0)
    {
        ans = ans*NUMBER;
        EXPO--;
    }
    return ans;
}

void Calculate_pos_power(int number, int expo)
{
    int NUMBER = number;
    int EXPO = expo;

    unsigned long long int ans = 1;

    unsigned long long int xxx=Driver(NUMBER,EXPO, ans);


    printf("Answer is : %llu ",xxx);
    printf("\n");
}

void Calculate_neg_power(int number, int expo)
{
    int NUMBER = number;
    int EXPO = expo;

    long long int ans = 1;
    long long int xxx = Driver(NUMBER,EXPO, ans);

    int Driver(NUMBER,EXPO, ans);
    printf("Answer is : %lli ",xxx);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int number;
    int expo;

    printf("Enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    printf("Enter the exponent\n");
    scanf("%d",&expo);

    if(number<0)
    {
        void Calculate_neg_power(number,expo);
    }
    else{
        void Calculate_pos_power(number,expo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i want that when number is less then 0, answer should be in long long int and when it is greater then 0 it should be in unsigned long long int.
but it does not return any value

Comment: what do you mean with "does not return any value"? At least something should be printed out...

Comment: it take number and expo from user but does not print any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually calling the functions:

```
if(number<0)
{
    void Calculate_neg_power(number,expo);
}
else{
    void Calculate_pos_power(number,expo);
}
```

These are function *declarations*, and invalid ones at that.

When calling a function, don't prefix it with the return type.

```
if(number<0)
{
    Calculate_neg_power(number,expo);
}
else{
    Calculate_pos_power(number,expo);
}
```

You also have a similar declaration inside one of your functions that isn't doing anything:

```
int Driver(NUMBER,EXPO, ans);
```

This can be removed.

Comment: Thanks, thats really a silly mistake which is bothering me from last one hour

Answer (score 0):

In `main`:

```
void Calculate_neg_power(number,expo);
```

is not the right way to call a function.

You should change it to:

```
Calculate_neg_power(number,expo);
```

The same thing goes for `Calculate_pos_power`.

Comment: Thanks, thats really a silly mistake which is bothering me from last one hour